# How to export Analysed data from Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spyder

I'm a beginner to Pandas. I added headers to a dataset which I imported earlier & it is working but when I'm trying to export the data it is exporting but not in format as I expected. Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance!

```
    #ExportingChangedData
import pandas as pd

headers = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration", "num-of-doors","body-style",
         "drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base", "length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type",
         "num-of-cylinders", "engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower",
         "peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]

url = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DS\IBM\Lab 1\imports-85.csv"

dft = pd.read_csv(url, names = headers)

exp = df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DS\IBM\Lab 1\DataExport1.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
print (dft)
print (exp)
```

Also, I'm not able to understand, why to put "r" before defining a file path? The example below for both import & export.

```
url = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DS\IBM\Lab 1\imports-85.csv"
```

If I'm not putting "r" before file path I'm getting below error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

A preview of the analyzed dataset: I want to export the data like this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CmWX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot do much about the colors, but you can add index and headers.

Also the reason to use r is to avoid escape sequences.

from this

```
url = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DS\IBM\Lab 1\imports-85.csv"
```

to this

```
url = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\DS\\IBM\\Lab 1\\imports-85.csv"
```

for the export options, you can use as below.

```
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DS\IBM\Lab1\imports-85.csv",index=True,header=True)
```

For more info , go through the docs here : [Pandas To CSV options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Hi @High-Octane defining file path is working but exporting data file is not working, Still need your help bro, thanks.

Comment: Edited, can you try that code again? Other than index and headers, is there anything else you want?

Comment: Hi @High-Octane I managed to export the data by making changes to that assigned variable but after export, it is showing all data in one column and their respective row. I need it on the bases of the column that I assigned.

Comment: Is your data separated by comma? If not, use a delimiter argument in your read csv pandas function

Comment: Add a sample, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: Expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNH89.png
Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2zEw.png

Note: Data is not missing, only not in the format @High-Octane

Comment: Either separate them by a delimiter. E.g. a pipe symbol '|' and use pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv',sep='|') or separate them by commas and just use pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv') because python compiler cannot recognize otherwise. E.g. = year,city, etc along with the values as well